# Including Info.plist in a Cocoa Static Library project in order to include in a framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, static-libraries

I have looked around forums and can't find a posting about this but I'm hoping someone can help.

**Issue:**
When you create a typical iOS project, Xcode automatically creates a <project name>-Info.plist file that gets preprocessed during the build phase to replace variables like: ${PRODUCT_NAME}.  This plist gets placed into the app bundle as Info.plist.

However, when you select the project type "Cocoa Static Library," this project type does not come with a <project name>-Info.plist file.  Without this file, doing a "Get Info" in Finder on a framework I'm creating out of this target won't show a "Version" number in the File Info pane.  We need to be able to version our framework package that we're building out of this static library and would like to include this Info.plist file.

I have tried to create a <project name>-Info.plist file populated with variables like ${PRODUCT_NAME} and specify the build settings "Expand Build Settings in Info.plist file" and "Preprocess Info.plist File" to YES.  However, the file doesn't get preprocessed.  Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I just watched a WWDC video where the presenter made the quick comment that Cocoa Static Library projects cannot process resources.  I have been searching for more details but I'm thinking this is the case.  Any ideas?